# Proper use of Output Buffer for a whole php clas

Tags: php, theme-development, oop

For my ajax popup login i want to use Output Buffer for a whole oop php class. I just want to *start buffering from the start of class and end it when the class is finished.*

```
class Wp_Ajax_Popup_Login {
    public function __construct() {
        // Output Buffering for whole class
        ob_start();
        add_action( 'after_switch_theme', array( $this, 'theme_activation' ) );
        add_action( 'switch_theme', array( $this, 'theme_deactivation' ) );

        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'start_session' ), 1 );

        add_action( 'wp_login', array( $this, 'end_session' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_logout', array( $this, 'end_session' ) );

        if( is_admin() ) {
            add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'custom_theme_option_menu' ) );
        }

        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'theme_login_enqueue_script' ) );

        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'ajax_login_modal_init' ) );
        add_shortcode( 'Bootstrap_Register_login', array( $this, 'theme_login_shortcode' ) );
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        // Is it will work for the whole class buffer cleanup?
        ob_end_clean();
    }

    public static function theme_activation() {}
    public function theme_deactivation() {}

    // Other functions will write here
}
new Wp_Ajax_Popup_Login();
```

End buffering at _destruct() magic method. Isn't it right way to **start buffering at the beginning of class and end when class end**. What is the right way ***use buffer for the whole php class***?

**EDIT**

Take a look and say where should i use ob_start() and ob_end_clean() for my ajax popupbox

```
// restrict direct access of theme files
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) )

class Wp_Ajax_Popup_Login {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'theme_login_enqueue_script' ) );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'ajax_login_modal_init' ) );
        add_shortcode( 'Bootstrap_Register_login', array( $this, 'theme_login_shortcode' ) );

        // Other necessary hooks will write here
    }


    public function theme_login_enqueue_script() {
        if (get_option( 'bootstrap_support_required' ) == 1){
            wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-bs3patch', get_parent_theme_file_uri( 'admin/assets/css/bootstrap-modal-bs3patch.css' ) );
        }

        //bootModal style
        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-modal', get_parent_theme_file_uri('admin/assets/css/bootstrap-modal.css') );

        // jquery
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        //bootmodal script
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'bootstrap-modal',
            get_parent_theme_file_uri( 'admin/assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js' ),
        false,'',true
        );
    }


    public function ajax_login_modal_init() {
        if ( ! is_admin() || is_customize_preview() ) {
            wp_register_script( 'ajax-login-script', get_parent_theme_file_uri( 'admin/assets/js/scripts.js' ), array( 'jquery' ) );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-login-script' );
        }

        wp_localize_script( 'ajax-login-script', 'ajax_login_object', array(
            'ajax_url'                 => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'login_nonce_token'        => wp_create_nonce( 'login_nonce' ),
            'register_nonce_token'     => wp_create_nonce( 'register_nonce' ),
            'lostpassword_nonce_token' => wp_create_nonce( 'lostpassword_nonce' ),
            'loginRedirectURL'         => (get_option( 'login_modal_redirect' ) == '') ? '' : get_option( 'login_modal_redirect' ),
            'registerRedirectURL'     => (get_option( 'register_modal_redirect' ) == '') ? '' : get_option( 'register_modal_redirect' )
        ) );

        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', array( $this, 'ajax_login_jquery_callable' ) );
        // add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxregister', array( $this, 'ajax_register_jquery_callable' ) );
        // add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlostpassword', array( $this, 'ajax_lost_password_jquery_callable' ) );
    }


    public function theme_login_shortcode() {
        // html forms
        add_action( 'wp_footer', array( $this, 'popup_bootmodal_form' ) );

        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            return '<button type="button" class="btn ' . $this->default_buttons() . ' ' . $this->theme_button_block() . ' ' . $this->theme_button_size() . '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bootmodal">' . $this->login_button_text() . '</button>';
        } else {
            if ( get_option( 'login_modals_profile' ) != 1 ) {
                return '<button type="button" class="btn ' . $this->default_buttons() . ' ' . $this->theme_button_block() . ' ' . $this->theme_button_size() . '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bootmodal">' . $this->login_button_text() . '</button>';
            } else {
                return '<button type="button" class="btn ' . $this->default_buttons() . ' ' . $this->theme_button_block() . ' ' . $this->theme_button_size() . ' disabled" disabled="disabled">' . $this->login_button_text() . '</button>';
            }
        }
    }


    // call it inside theme_login_shortcode() function
    public function popup_bootmodal_form() {
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) :
            ?>

                <div id="bootmodal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="370" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active fade in" id="login_tab">
                            <?php include_once 'templates/login-form.php'; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php if (get_option( 'users_can_register' ) == true): ?>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="register_tab">
                                <?php include_once 'templates/register-form.php'; ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="lostpass_tab">
                            <?php  include_once 'templates/password-lost-form.php'; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- #tab-content -->
                </div><!-- #bootmodal -->

            <?php
        endif;
    }

    // Other functions will write here


}
new Wp_Ajax_Popup_Login();
```

I think, this time i give you all the code you need to understand that where should i use **ob_start() and ob_end_clean()**.

Thanks.

.

Comment: Why? I can't imagine any reason you'd want to do this. `add_action()` doesn't even produce any output, so there's no reason to buffer it.

Comment: @jacob Peattie - i write my reason in below

Comment: I have no idea why your example is using output buffering either. It makes no sense to use it in either context. The only thing that _might_ need to be output buffered is the contents of the shortcode function, but in that case the output buffering should start and end inside just that function.

Comment: @jacob you mean only **included html files**  files need to output buffered?

Comment: Correct. You only need to output buffer if you need to capture output. If you want to capture the contents of a file into a variable, you will need to output buffer the include, but you shouldn't need to output buffer an entire class or plugin.

Comment: @jacob this time i provide all my class code that you need to understand where should use ob_start() and ob_end_clean() correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not need to use output buffering anywhere. There's nowhere that you need it.

Your shortcode function is already properly using `return` for the output output, so nothing needs to be captured, and your `popup_bootmodal_form()` function is outputting in `wp_footer`, which is fine, and doesn't need to be captured either.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hey @jacob will you help me about this question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/377578/woocommerce-order-status-last-time-who-change-that-person-user-name-or-id-i